json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data - error when reading from database using python
I am trying to read a json column from SingleStore database using 'singlestoredb' library in Python. Below is the code.
import singlestoredb as s2
import pandas as pd

query = """
select  
uuid   
,output           
,environment        
from table_name where  uuid = 'aaa' and environment = 'live'
"""

conn = s2.connect(
    user = " ",
    password = " ",
    host = " ",
    port = " ",
    database = " ",
    results_type='dict',
    charset='utf8mb4'
    )

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(query)
    df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall()) 
    print(df)


This piece of code is throwing below exception ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Python/test_singlestoredb.py", line 61, in <module>
    cur.execute(query)
  File ".../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/singlestoredb/mysql/cursors.py", line 208, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File ".../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/singlestoredb/mysql/cursors.py", line 393, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File ".../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/singlestoredb/mysql/connection.py", line 863, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File ".../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/singlestoredb/mysql/connection.py", line 1228, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File ".../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/singlestoredb/mysql/connection.py", line 1643, in read
    self._read_result_packet(first_packet)
  File ".../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/singlestoredb/mysql/connection.py", line 1725, in _read_result_packet
    self._read_rowdata_packet()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 137182 (char 137181)


But, same script works fine when I put 'output' column at the end of the select list like below.
query = """
select  
uuid   
,environment    
,output               
from table_name where  uuid = 'aaa' and environment = 'live'
"""

'output' column contains a large JSON value. It is in proper json format.
Below is the column length details.
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| length(uuid) | length(output) | length(trim(output)) | length(output_text) | length(environment) |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|           36 |         137189 |               137189 |              138342 |                   4 |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

Column definition in table:
'output' JSON COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
Can't put the 'output' column at the end always. Could you please help me on this.
Thanks,
Anand.
Tried different encoding. Datatype conversion. Checked online.

when I got this error in the past, the solution was to add the parameter pure_python = 'true' to the s2.connect block :
conn = s2.connect(
    user = " ",
    password = " ",
    host = " ",
    port = " ",
    database = " ",
    results_type='dict',
    charset='utf8mb4',
    pure_python = 'true'
    )

